# Converting data to props for root component in Vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This must be simple, but haven't cracked it...

In vue, I think I get how to pass *props* from parent to child components.  And I understand that I have an app state in the `data` member of the vue instance.  What I don't understand is how to get the `data` state into the root app as props.

It seems there are a few ways to organize a vue app, so here's what I'm trying to make work:

index.ts

```
import app from './app.vue'

export default new Vue({
    // App Root Element
    el: '#app',
    render: (c) => c('app'),
    components: {
      app
    },
    data: {
        someValue: 42
    }
})
```

app.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        Some Value: {{someValue}}
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    export default {
        props: ['someValue']
    };
</script>
```

I assume it should be something like the following, but I don't know how to get a reference directly to the `data` - unless I keep a reference to it outside of vue for this purpose, but that seems like it should not be necessary:

```
render: (c) => c('app', { someValue: ??? }),
```

Comment: Hi, why do you want to pass data to the app? what kind of data? something like an initial state?

Comment: @JOjohn I think the question is how do you pass props using a `render` function (instead of a template)?

Comment: One problem is that your template in `app.vue` doesn't have a wrapping element. Each template must have a single root element.

Comment: wrapping element - oops, just a mistake in trimming down the example. thanks

Comment: @RoyJ hi, yes that's what I understood, but i was wondering if the use of a EventBus or a store wouldn't be possible and a bit more practical?

Comment: @JOjohn - I’m trying to understand each layer (basic vuejs) before adding additional mechanisms which are strictly optional conveniences.  All the todo, etc examples mount html already on the page or don’t have any data.

Comment: Have you read [this section](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) of the docs?

Comment: @JasonKleban Sure, that sounds like a good approach. 
As far as i know you can pass an object as second attribute that countains a itself a props object. to the function executed by the render function as such ('app', {props:{}})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `this` to get data or property values inside your render method (or methods or computed values, etc). Don't use an arrow function to define your render function if you're going to use `this` inside it.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(c) {
    return c('app', {props:{someValue: this.someValue}})
  },
  components: {
    app
  },
  data: {
    someValue: 42
  }
})
```

Example.

```js
console.clear()

const app = {
  props: ["someValue"],
  template: `<div>Some Value: {{someValue}}</div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(c) {
    return c('app', {props:{someValue: this.someValue}})
  },
  components: {
    app
  },
  data: {
    someValue: 42
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
</div>
```

As @RoyJ pointed out, this is the [key section of the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth).

Comment: I love this site